# Socket.IO and Express session not sharing their session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, express-session

I am trying to connect the sessions of express API and socket.IO server. But it seems both are storing their sessions separately. The socket.IO have the connections session while the express server has the user qid session. I am using express `^4.17.1` and socket.IO `^4.1.2`. Here is my code:

**/server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const sharedSession = require("express-socket.io-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(cookieParser("secret"));
const corsConfig = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
};

const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, { cors: corsConfig });

const whitelist = ["http://localhost:3000", "http://192.168.2.104:3000"];

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: "keyboard cat",
  cookie: { maxAge: 60000 },
  name: "qid",
});
// register middleware in Express
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
// register middleware in Socket.IO
io.use((socket, next) => {
  sessionMiddleware(socket.request, {}, next);
  // sessionMiddleware(socket.request, socket.request.res, next); will not work with websocket-only
  // connections, as 'socket.request.res' will be undefined in that case
});

// TRIED, BUT SAME RESULT. . .
// io.use(sharedSession(sessionMiddleware, { autoSave: true }));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  req.session.qid = "sdfdsfsadgfas";
  req.session.save();
  console.log(
    "CONNECTIONS / QID (EXPRESS SERVER)",
    req.session.connections,
    req.session.qid
  );
  res.json({ success: true });
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  const session = socket.request.session;
  // console.log(socket.request);
  if (!session.connections) session.connections = 0;
  session.connections++;
  session.save();
  socket.on("a", () => {
    session.reload((err) => {
      if (err) console.log("ERROR", err);

      console.log(
        "CONNECTIONS / QID (IO SERVER)",
        session.connections,
        session.qid
      );
    });
  });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(port, () => console.log("server listening on port " + port));
```

**/client.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.3/socket.io.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-cPwlPLvBTa3sKAgddT6krw0cJat7egBga3DJepJyrLl4Q9/5WLra3rrnMcyTyOnh"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script>
    const socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/").then(() => socket.emit("a"));
  </script>
</html>
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They should be - express is a web server, socket.io is a websocket server; their sessions are very much not the same thing, with express only acting as pass-through mediator for setting up a websocket connection. As web server, express receives an HTTP GET request with an "upgrade this connection to a websocket connection please" instruction, which it honours by handing it over to socket.io instead of doing anything itself. After which express is done: it is never involved in any of the websocket communication and should not know anything about socket sessions.

Comment: I see, do you know anyway to merge the sessions?

Comment: Why would you need to? What problem are you trying to solve that requires both of them to have access to the same session data? (because that's almost certainly not necessary).

Comment: Basically, I need to get the user id from API's session after logging in to store their respective socket id with their user id.

Comment: Please let me know if there is a better way to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: That's not session information, that's "user information", so I'd strongly recommend writing a user class for holding information like that. The user logs into your web server, you create their user object, their browser asks for a websocket connection, your web server asks socket.io to take over and you make your code add a `user` property to the socket it builds, pointing to that user object.

Comment: How will I know that the user is authenticated in socket.io server? The only way I can think of is to get API's session.

Comment: again: the web server is the mediator for _any_ connection getting established, so the web server decides whether someone has correctly authenticated. If they haven't, you don't allow the web socket connection. If they have, you do. There is no reason for the websocket to know anything about the web server's session management.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your answers! It really helped me out to understand these processes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the encrypted session id in the front while connecting, and decrypt it in backend...

**Front**

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:5000?session=sessionIdEncrypted");
```

**Backend**

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
    const givenSessionId = socket.handshake.query.session
    // here you decrypt the session id and find it in the store
})
```

Comment: I am using httpOnly Cookies. How can I access that from my code?

Comment: You can first call your backend and ask the session id, and then, connect the socket.io with the retrieved sessionId...

Comment: That sounds good, but wouldn't the purpose of httpOnly property be lost if users can get the session ID? calling the API rather than accessing the  cookie directly. I am storing the sessionId in the httpOnly cookie. Sorry, I am a beginner, please let me know if my point is not correct.

Comment: Here there is no question about cookies, you give the encrypted session id, and retrieve the session by its id.... You have the session id, so you can do like the doc says [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session#storegetsid-callback), you get the session at the connection, so once retrieved, you can pass it at every socket 'on message'

Comment: Would that mean there is no need to bind the express session socket middleware to the socket.io?